# PHP form validation using preg_match for password checks

Tags: php, html

This is a general question on password form validation and using a combination of uppercase, lowercase, numbers and characters used.

Research has showed that preg_match is required to validate the password (or whatever variable you use): (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/")

Though how would how would i integrate this into the if statement below? I've tried combining them using && though this seems to ignore the preg_match part. if(($pass == $pass2) && (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/"))

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<?php

require "dbconn.php";

$username = ($_GET['username']);
$email = ($_GET['email']);
$pass = ($_GET['pwd1']);
$pass2 = ($_GET['pwd2']);
$USN = ($_GET['schoolnumber']);

$matching = 0;

if($pass == $pass2)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.alert('Your details have been successfully    registered, please proceed to login with your new credentials!')</script>";
echo '<script>javascript:window.close();</script>';


$query = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES     ('".$username."','".$email."','".$pass."','face1.jpg','".$USN."','N')";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$results1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());
}
else{

header('Location:register.php?matching=1');

}
?>
```

Comment: Please define "this does not seem to work"

Comment: Indeed, this code looks more or less correct to me, though you really, REALLY shouldn't be using mysql_* (it's deprecated) and you should really, REALLY be santizing your inputs before inserting into the database. The code as-is would be WIDE OPEN to any SQL injection attacks.

Comment: the code works but when do I use an opperand like ($pass == $pass2 && preg_match("/^.(?=.{8,})(?=.[0-9])(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z]).*$/") ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match` requires two arguments the pattern to look for and the string to test. Plus I'm not sure if the regular expression you are using would work anyway. Try something like.

```
$pattern = '/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/';
if (($pass1 == $pass2) && preg_match($pattern, $pass1)) {
    ...
}
```

You only need to match against one of the passwords because should ($pass1 == $pass2) fail then the preg_match isn't even preformed.

The regex above checks that the password is at least 8 characters long and contains at least one of each of lowercase, uppercase and a number

Comment: Thank you for you our assistance, its been greatly appreciated